# tensorflow.keras.Tokenizer - AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower' with no null values and no column with floats

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, text, tokenize

All the answers I have read on stackoverflow for similar errors either suggested to fix null values or fix the datatypes. I neither have nulls in my dataframe or floats. But, the error still persists.

Here's some information about my data:
about null values(as I know `numpy.nan`s are encoded as floats in pandas):
[image]
about data types:
[image]

And when I do:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
title_tokeniser = Tokenizer(num_words=10)
title_tokeniser.fit_on_texts(train_set.loc[:,'title'] + test_set.loc[:,'title'])
```

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-26b704f1c0a1> in <module>()
      1 title_tokeniser = Tokenizer(num_words=10)
----> 2 title_tokeniser.fit_on_texts(train_set.loc[:,'title'] + test_set.loc[:,'title'])
      3 
      4 # unique tokens found in titles are:
      5 title_token_index = title_tokeniser.word_index

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in fit_on_texts(self, texts)
    223                                             self.filters,
    224                                             self.lower,
--> 225                                             self.split)
    226             for w in seq:
    227                 if w in self.word_counts:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
     41     """
     42     if lower:
---> 43         text = text.lower()
     44 
     45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

EDIT:
Here's what I have done in the process of debugging and trying to fix this problem:

I even made sure that I have removed all numbers by doing:

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', ' ', text)
```

on each row of all columns of both my train and test sets.

And also checked if turning off `lower` argument does anything by initialising a `Tokenizer` instance by doing:

```
title_tokeniser = Tokenizer(num_words=10, lower=None)
```

But, the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I couldn't trace the presence of any floats or nulls in my data. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
texts = pd.concat([train_set['title'] , test_set['title']],axis=0).astype("str")
   
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenize
title_tokeniser = Tokenizer(num_words=10)
title_tokeniser.fit_on_texts(texts)
```